# What is the difference between RegexpTokenizer and spacy tokenizer?

Tags: nlp

```
import spacy
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
EN = spacy.load('en')

def tokenize_docstring(text):
    "Apply tokenization using spacy to docstrings."
    tokens = EN.tokenizer(text)
    return [token.text.lower() for token in tokens if not token.is_space]


def tokenize_code(text):
    "A very basic procedure for tokenizing code strings."
    return RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+').tokenize(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

`spacy` has many more capabilities including word relationships, adding named entities to words etc.; following the [official documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching)

> Compared to using regular expressions on raw text, spaCy’s rule-based matcher engines and components not only let you find the words and phrases you’re looking for – they also give you access to the tokens within the document and their relationships. This means you can easily access and analyze the surrounding tokens, merge spans into single tokens or add entries to the named entities in doc.ents.